# Change a subsite Admin role of a WordPress Multisite after 24 hours registering

Tags: multisite, users, editor, blog

please I am trying to change WordPress multisite users' role after registration. So a new user can register and create a subsite and after 24 hours the users' role changes to the subscriber role. The reason I am doing this is to make sure they submit a KYC/Means of Identification on or before 24 hours of creating the subsite. I tried with the code below, but having issues implementing the time.

Please I will appreciate all contributions and support to this topic.

```
function woo_admin_to_editor($blog_id, $user_id) {
 switch_to_blog($blog_id);
 $user = new WP_User($user_id);
 if ($user->exists()) {
   $user->set_role('subscriber');
 }  
 restore_current_blog();
}

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'woo_admin_to_editor', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [the built-in cron scheduler](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/).

You've got two options: either

1. set up a one-off job to downgrade the user 24 hours after registering using [wp_schedule_single_event()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/)
2. instead set up a daily job with [wp_schedule_event()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) to check all blogs for users without KYC data and deactivate them if necessary.

You should probably change your code above so that it checks for KYC data (stored in user meta? or a post on the site?) and also sends the user an email notification of the change too.

Note that WordPress cron events only run when there's web traffic. If you have lots of traffic then that should be fine: else they'll get delayed until the next web request to the site. You might want to set up [the system task scheduler](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/) to trigger cron events.

Comment: Thank you so kindly for your response. 

It is a small multisite and all I am looking at is to add an interval(time) to the code, so the user role changes. Once that is done! if he/she tries to login - 

I have a message that tells them you won't be able to login until you feel the KYC form. Once they do, I will change the role manually for now